# Unreachable code detected within an if statement for login screen?

Tags: c#

```
public void Login()
    {

        //Admin login temp
        if (txtusername.Text == "admin" && txtpassword.Text == "admin123")
        {
            Form mainmenu = new frmmainmenu();
            Useraccounts.LoggedInUsername = txtusername.Text;
            this.Hide();
            mainmenu.Show();
            return;
```

Error is here user accounts is displaying as unreachable code, have a class for user accounts detailing 6 user accounts and LoggedInUsername variable

```
            //Make new object of useraccounts class for logging in
            **Useraccounts** Loginattempt = new Useraccounts();


            //Retrieve the number of accounts there are to run the loop the appropriate number of times
            int NoOfAccounts = Loginattempt.Username.Length;

            for (int i = 0; i <= NoOfAccounts; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    //Checking the username against the class & check if password matches
                    if (txtusername.Text == Loginattempt.Username[i])
                    {
                        if (txtpassword.Text == Loginattempt.Password[i])
                        {
                            Form Mainmenu = new frmmainmenu();
                            Useraccounts.LoggedInUsername = txtusername.Text;
                            this.Hide();
                            Mainmenu.Show();
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    //If the username cannot be found do nothing.
                }
            }

            {
                MessageBox.Show("Incorrect username or password.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Is this all one method? You're calling `return;` in the previous line.

Comment: Putting text like this right in the middle of your code isn't a good idea when asking for help. I'm almost certain this is all one method, and Lee is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Return
```

means that execution of the function is stopped and given value is returned. 
Since you are running a method you do not need a `return`.

```
public void Login()
    {
    //Admin login temp
    if (txtusername.Text == "admin" && txtpassword.Text == "admin123")
    {
        Form mainmenu = new frmmainmenu();
        Useraccounts.LoggedInUsername = txtusername.Text;
        this.Hide();
        mainmenu.Show();
        return; <----**delete this return**
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a try catch here, as the execution won't continue if the return executed successfully. Just throw an error after the return, which will execute if the return didn't work